# C#, OLEDB reading a Excel file from a specified row

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I need to read a table in an Excel file starting from 10th row (rows before 10th row are having other data and they are not in a correct format and coteins banners, cell splits, ect) using Ado.Net. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. Specially [Simen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619275/simen-s). I've managed to find a solution for my problem with some help from this article: [OleDb connection to Excel; how do I select fixed width, unbounded height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138197/oledb-connection-to-excel-how-do-i-select-fixed-width-unbounded-height)

Comment: how did you do it? care to share?

Comment: thanks I had same issue, This helps me to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

It's all here: [How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934). The article contains code samples for to VB.NET, but the C# code shouldn't be too difficult to deduce.

Pay particular attention to the section specifying *Table Naming Conventions*

Comment: Hi Simen, Thanks for replying. But is the articale the range should be fixed. And what I only know is the starting row no. I don't know the end row no or the column name.

Comment: It sounds like your Excel data source isn't structured in the way that I would prefer if I was embarking on implementing an interface to it. You could use Excel automation to initially evaluate the layout of the Excel sheet (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) but I wouldn't really recommend going down that route.